# Combine two separate lists of users using another list of all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Might be a little desperate, or over thinking this, but I'm tying to simplify what someone else has already put in place.

There's a list of users, and a list of admins. A third list is a list of all user accounts, but only lists the account IDs - the other two lists hold account information (including the IDs).

I'm attempting to create a single list of all user accounts, with all the account information, but getting nowhere.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
everyone_list.join(
  (users_list, 
    a => a.id, 
    b => b.id, 
    (a, b) => new { 
      id 
    })).join(
      admins_list, 
      a => a.id, 
      b => b.id,
      (a, b) => new {
        id
      }).tolist
```

I think the issue is that the first join wont have any information (ids) for the second join.

Comment: Are admins and users both the same type? It would be helpful if you provided sample input (i.e. instantiate a small sample of each list you want to combine in code) and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that admins and users are the same type (I'll call it PersonInfo) and the list of account ids is a simple list of integers, you can do it with Linq.

accountIdList is the list of all account ids, adminList is your list of admins, and userList is your list of users.

```
var accountInfoList = userList.Concat(adminList)
    .Where(user => accountIdList.Contains(user.Id))
    .ToList();
```

If they are not the same type, I would suggest creating an interface containing the fields that are common between the two and adjust the above to cast the users and admins as the inteface type.